# Bitmap in ListView: Loading slowly

Tags: android, image, bitmap, loading

In my ListView, I have one ImageView and two TextViews in every row. The pictures for the ListView are loaded from the memory of my Galaxy Nexus. I already downscaled it to 100x100 using

```
Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(de, 80, 80, true);
```

but it still needs a few seconds to load.

What can I do?

EDIT:

```
public Bitmap resizeBitmap(String path){
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(path);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,options);
    try {
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(path);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // here w and h are the desired width and height
    options.inSampleSize = Math.max(options.outWidth/100, options.outHeight/100);
    // bitmap is the resized bitmap
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,options);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First point i can see from your code that you are decoding the stream twice...the first place where it is decoded its not being even used anywhere....So removing that statement will increase the execution speed of your code.

```
 //BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,options); comment this line
try {
    is.close();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Also may I ask why can you not use the Thumbnails of the pictures? instead of resizing every image....if you are trying to display thumbnails of images in your app

Yes there is a whole table that stores the thumbanil of images you need to access it via Cursor api for example:

```
    Cursor mediaCursor = managedQuery(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null,
            null, null);
```

From this cursor you can get the imageId and then with the help of image Id you can retreive the thumbnail of the image by using the `MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail()` method for example below is some code that will help:

```
     Bitmap thumbBitmap = null;

    thumbBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(cr, imageID, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
    if(thumbBitmap != null){
        return new BitmapDrawable(thumbBitmap);
    }
```

Comment: Is there a way to use the thumbnails? Searched a lot but only found the possibility to downscale the originial bitmaps

Answer (score 0):

Displaying bitmaps in ListView efficiently is a fairly complex task that involves quite a lot of variables. I would suggest you reading [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) and downloading a code example they provide. This is an excellent starting point and in simple cases may be enough to be copy-pasted.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to load them in `AsyncTask`. Here you have a great video that shows this approach:
https://developers.google.com/events/io/2012/sessions/gooio2012/103/